# Warning: skipping unsupported geometry type 'Compound Curve' when using v.transform

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, convert, dxf

I am trying to transform data in QGIS from a DXF file.

I keep getting the error:

> Warning: skipping unsupported geometry type. Compound Curve

when I do a `v.transform`.

Eventually, I want to store the data in a shapefile.

Comment: How did you import you data into QIGS? Did you validate the geometry of you data in QGIS, e.g. topology? What kind of geometry type does your data posses? Can you show us the way your data looks like?

Comment: See the "supported entities" in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html. At least some curved geometries should be converted into line segments. Could you check if some geometries are not converted at all as the warning text "skipping" suggests.

Answer (score 1):

GIS vector data such as shapefiles does not support curved lines. It only supports lines connected by vertices. So you lose the curves, they are transformed to vertices, thus with "edges". That is what the message means.

To convert DXF files to Shapefiles, have a look at the
[AnotherDXFImporter](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/) plugin.

Comment: Is there a way to transform the curve to the vertices

Comment: See updated answer.